# Import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting cannot resolved error while importing 
android.support.v7.app.Fragment.

I tried all solution which is given in different threads.
Am I missing something please help.

1. I have downloaded android support libraries.
2. `minSdkVersion 14   targetSdkVersion 14`
3. added library in dependency

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
   }
   ```
4. synchronize build.gradle file (Right click on file --> Synchronize
   'build.gradle') and Clean your project (Build --> Clean Project)
       after the change.

**Still I am not able to reslove this. Please help**

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.effectivenavigation"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.effectivenavigation"
        android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".CollectionDemoActivity" android:label="@string/demo_collection" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: do you have 22.1.1 version installed on your PC, check SDK manager?

Comment: yes sdk have android support library 22.1.1 version.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
 import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
```

with

```
 import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't comment.
try using

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
```

lower version fix that for me.

Comment: Still Same... No luck :(

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on your project, choose **Open Module Settings**, then in the module settings window, click on **Modules/app**. Then in the right side of the window chose the **Dependencies** TAB. Then press the **PLUS sign** and chose '**Library dependency**'.
In the new shown window, select your support library and click **Ok**

Comment: I added library dependency through this path only